# mobile css not being targeted

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a project that has different layouts depending on the device you use to access it. I am using the following line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="mobile_style.css" />
```

on my html to access a different file with the css for mobile devices. The line is below the general css one. The css is not being targeted for mobile.

here is the site.

http://maxruiz-portraits.com

To make things worse and more confusing, I copied and pasted code that I had written for this site:

http://maxruiz-parana.com

And there the link tag works. Any ideas as to why much appreciated. I can post code if you'd like or you can look at it in browser.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache and reloading the page?

Comment: Yes both on the computer and on the phone.

Comment: It's definitely working on my side: http://i.imgur.com/SdBD3aX.png

Comment: works fine for me. i also think it's a cache problem.

Comment: So, hold on, when you look at it on a mobile device, can you access the menu through the "info" icon at the top right? For me it's not showing both on tablet and phone. Surely cache problems on two devices...

Answer (score 0):

your `link` tags are in the `body` of the website, not in the `head`, where they should be